# How can I merge a branch into master but continue working on the branch?

Tags: git, branch

I created a branch to try a different approach and it worked, so I would like to merge the "Farmcrops" branch into "Master" to keep those changes but continue the "Farmcrops" branch to explore another possibility. That way, if this latest change doesn't work, I can revert back to "Master" which would now include the first round of changes.

How can I do that?

Comment: The new exploration is still based on my changing cropfarms to farmcrops so it made sense to me to keep using that branch but if it is easier in git to merge and branch again, I can do that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is the process you are looking for:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git merge Farmcrops`
3. `git push origin master`
4. `git branch -d Farmcrops`
5. `git checkout master`
6. `git checkout -b Farmcrops`
7. continue your commits on the branch `Farmcrops`...

Branches are just pointers, it's very easy to create/delete a branch and if your branch `Farmcrops` isn't pushed on remote repository, there is absolutely no dependency with it. You can delete it after the merge and recreate it from the master.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You shouldn't merge `Farmcrops` directly into `master`, though. It would be safer to first merge `master` into `Farmcrops`, check that everything works there, and only then merge `Farmcrops` into `master`.

Comment: @Jubobs thank you for the advice, i never tried this approach. But the merging action is done locally, you have all the time you want to validate the new version, test it and ensure that everything is alright, no? It seems to be a useless step to first merge as you're suggested

Comment: Even if everything is local, the first merge is useful in that it promotes isolation: it saves you the risk of creating a "bad" commit on `master` and having to reset `master` to one of its parent, or revert the last commit on `master`. It's a safety net.

Comment: Ok i understand the advantage of doing this way. When i'm facing such kind of "bad" commit i usually reset it in order to restore the previous state and fix my issue

Comment: That works as well, but `reset` is a potentially riskier operation. That's why I like merging `master` into the feature branch first.

Comment: I'll try that the next time i'm facing this situation. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Why recreating and not just continuing? If Farmcrops is not just locally but also on a server (f.i. for backup-security), then one would need to delete it locally and remotely, create it locally again, push it to remote, track it again.......and so one. Isnt merging into master and continuing a lot easier?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin, So you switched to `master` and merged `Farmcrops` into `master`. This happened locally! Then you pushed local `master` to the remote `master`. 
Q1: Until now, if I've pushed `Farmcrops ` changes remotely too, does it gonna effect continue working on the same branch locally in any way?  
Q2. Then, you deleted all local commits on `Farmcrops ` branch and checkout the latest `master`. 5th step wasn't needed? since after deleting `Farmcrops ` locally you're left with `master` only, isn't it? so the pointer will switch automatically to local `master`, correct?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin,Q3. if I cont. on `Farmcrops`, and suppose someone spins up a news feature branch say `newFarm` out of latest remote `master` and keep working on it, and then merge to master as you explained above and made a "new latest `master`", but I'm still working on `Farmcrops` and now I want to merge with the "new lastest` master`" branch, how I'm gonna make that happen? Basically I need to achieve changes from `newfarm` branch after it gets merged in `master` and at the same time preserve the clean history of commits, how the project devlpd over time. A clean network graph of the commits.

Comment: @Anu  Q1: If you pushed the branch to your remote, after the merge+delete action on the branch you should also push these changes on your remote. Q2: Deleting the branch after mergin into master will not delete the commits. But you're correct the 5th step is just there to ensure that we're on the `master` branch, if you do all steps at the same moment it will not be needed to do this checkout.

Comment: @Anu Q3: In this case, to include all modifications done on the remote `master` before merging your branch, a `rebase` will be the solution to keep a clean history.

Answer (score 118):

If I understand correctly, you're starting from

```
-- o -- o -- o [master]
    \
     o -- o [Farmcrops]
```

You shouldn't merge `Farmcrops` directly into `master`, because you run the risk of breaking the code in `master`, which, by convention, is supposed to be more stable. Instead, check out `Farmcrops` and merge `master` into it.

```
git checkout Farmcrops
git merge master
```

Then you'll get

```
-- o -- o -- o [master]
    \         \
     o -- o -- o [HEAD -> Farmcrops]
```

Run some tests; make sure everything works as expected. Then check out `master` and merge `Farmcrops` into it:

```
git checkout master
git merge Farmcrops
```

Your repo will then look like this:

```
-- o -- o -- o
    \         \
     o -- o -- o [HEAD -> master,Farmcrops]
```

(Note that this merge is a *fast forward*: it doesn't create a merge commit because `Farmcrops` is a direct descendant of `master`.)

Now check out `Farmcrops` again and continue your experiment, make more commits on it, etc...

```
-- o -- o -- o
    \         \
     o -- o -- o [master]
                \
                 o -- o -- o [HEAD -> Farmcrops]
```

You can always fall back on `master` (which now contains "the first round of changes", as you put it) if your new experiment on `Farmcrops` doesn't pan out so well.

Comment: The visuals on this are very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to put them in.

Comment: Note that the second merge doesn't need to create another merge commit because `Farmcrops` is a direct descendent of `master`. It just moves the pointer (fast-forward). This helped me understand the graph.

Comment: This is why you should always read past the accepted answer and look for one with more votes!

Comment: If you merge Farmcrops into master you also have all changes from master in Farmcrops? I thought Farmcrops is still an independent branch after a merge, but it seems not.

Comment: @SamMcCreery Thanks. I've added a note about that in my answer.

Comment: @jub0bs , suppose someone spins up a news feature branch say newFarm out of latest remote master and keep working on it, and then merge to master as you explained above and made a "new latest master", but I'm still working on Farmcrops and now I want to merge with the "new lastest` master" branch, how I'm gonna make that happen? Basically I need to achieve changes from newfarm` branch after it gets merged in master and at the same time preserve the clean history of commits, how the project devlpd over time. A clean network graph of the commits.  https://pastebin.com/dKUTXazV

Comment: @Anu You should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

In the link below it is explained how to create a hotfix branch, make changes and merge it to the master. Only difference, hotfix branch is deleted after merge.

Just use Farmcrops as a branch name and do not delete branch after merge.

[GIT-SCM: Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

[STEP 1] Create a branch and make your changes

```
$ git checkout Farmcrops
Switched to a new branch 'Farmcrops'
$ vim index.html
$ git commit -a -m 'fix the broken email address'
[Farmcrops 3a0874c] fix the broken email address
 1 files changed, 1 deletion(-)
```

[STEP 2] Then, go back to master branch and merge

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge Farmcrops
Updating f42c576..3a0874c
Fast-forward
 README | 1 -
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
```

And, if you want to make more changes on the same branch, apply [step 1] again.

When you complete changes apply [step 2] again.

Follow these steps as much as required.

Once you finished your job with this branch you can delete it.

```
$ git branch -d Farmcrops
Deleted branch Farmcrops (was 3a0874c).
```

NOT: Instead of merge I suggest rebase [GIT-SCM: Rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html)

```
git rebase Farmcrops
```

Comment: I change the statement; "git checkout -b Farmcrops" --> "git checkout Farmcrops" since, branch aready exists and STEP 1 can be applied several times.

Answer (score 1):

1. Merge feature branch PR
2. Delete feature branch on GitHub
3. `git branch -d feature-branch`
4. `git checkout -b feature-branch`