# Should I merge master into a branch, and then merge back into master?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

I have the following branches:

- `master`
- `test1`, which was created from `master`
- `test2`, which was also created from `master`.

I've done multiple commits on the `test1` branch, and also, since I created the `test1` branch, I've created multiple commits on `master`.

There are also commits on `test2`, which I intend to merge back into `master` later.

The thing right now is that I need my changes from `master`, and if possible, from `test2` on `test1`.

I want to know if I can merge `master` into `test1`, so I get the commits from `master` on `test`, and after I finish my feature on `test1`, merge that again to `master`. Is that possible? Or it will raise conflicts?

Is it possible to merge also `test2` into `test1`, then merge `test2` into `master`, and, finally, merge `test1` into `master`?

Will Git understand that some commits are already merged into the branch that is being merged?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024586/git-i-want-to-merge-a-branch-to-master-but-continue-working-on-the-branch

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I want to know if I can merge MASTER into TEST1, so I get the commits from master on test, and after I finish my feature on test1, merge that again to MASTER. is that possible? or it will raise conflicts?

That exactly how it is done. You may get conflict when you merge master into test1, that you have to resolve manually. After that you should be able to merge test1 into master without conflicts.

> If thats possible, is possible to merge also test2 into test1, next merge test2 into master, and next merge test1 into master?

It is possible, but not advisable. Instead merge master into test2, then test2 back to master. (The same what you have done to test1.)

**After this all your changes should be in master.**

> Will git understand that some commits are already merged into the branch that is being merged?

Yes, unlike SVN, Git is aware of such commits.

Comment: Is it bad practice to merge master into feature branch instead of rebasing?

Comment: I prefer not rebasing, so +1 for this answer.

Comment: Basil, why you prefer to not rebase?

Comment: Merging master/dev into feature and merge back feature into master/dev is a project killing. By doing this you take responsibility in your branch by committing these changes from master/dev to your branch. And then, when merging back your are "applying" your work + this commit from master/dev that you are not supposed to have. I found personally this method to be a bad practice and can lead to loss of code. If you are the only one working on your branch, then just rebase, or worth case scenario create a temp branch to cherry pick your branch's commit and the reset your branch on it.

Comment: @OlegG. I guess we need to distinguish two cases here: Merging master into feature and then directly merging the feature branch back into master (preferrably through a pull request, possibly including deletion of the branch) is perfectly safe and provides a fully traceable history as opposed to rebase (sometimes you are forced to provide that). However, merging master into a feature branch somewhere in the middle, or several times can easily cause troubles when merging back to master, possibly with accidental loss of code as you said.

Comment: @OlegG. Can you please elaborate more about the problematics of back and forth merges between feature and the integration  branches? How does that lead to a "data loss"? As far as I know git is pretty good on tracking the source of a certain change and will make those merges in a pretty safe way.

Answer (score 13):

To keep a branch always up-to-date with master and raise no conflicts when merging back to it you could do the following:

```
git checkout test1
git rebase master
```

At this point you will be up to date with master and have your commits on test1 on top of it.

`rebase` would do the following:

- Pick all commits on test1 after a point it differs from master and put in a temporary area.
- Pick all commits from master after the point it differs from test1 and bring them to test1. At this point both branches are up-to-date.
- Then it will pick up test1 commits from the temporary area and apply them on top of test1. At this point test1 will be up-to-date with master and have its commits on top.
  When it happens, any conflict that may exist will show up, and you can resolve them.

After this, merging back to master will be a fast-forward.

```
git checkout master
git merge test1
```

What I like about this approach is the following:

- It's simple.
- Makes easy keep up-to-date with branches.
- Eliminates merge commits, because conflicts are resolved upon rebase.

I've applied this for quite some time, and it seems to fit what you're trying to accomplish.

A [visual explanation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) of how rebasing works may also be helpful.

Comment: Both test1 and test2 are tracked (with all his commits) by a remote repository, I've heard that is not good to idea to do rebase for branches that have commits on remote repositories?

Comment: Yes, unless you do all of this before pushing, which is the idea. No problems with it at all. Try with a small project and see if it fits you.

Comment: I've had some strange experience with get rebase today. Imagine, I have version 1 in the master branch, then in feature branch I sequentially upgrade the app to v2, 3 and then 4 (that's where it stays in the HEAD of feature branch). Now, I'm doing git rebase master, get conflict (say, on "upgrade from v1 to v2" commit) and what do I see?? "Incoming change: v2" (okey). "Current change: v4"… WUT? What should I do here? I expected all my feature-branch commits be rolled back to the "branching point", then moving to master's current HEAD and re-aplying feature commits on top of it…

Comment: @pilat I see, maybe this link would help illustrate and clarify better on scenarios with which you may identify with: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing